# Arithmetic overflow error: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff, dateadd

I've got an issue with a stored procedure causing an:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

The are two tables, the first pulls in data from an ODBC connection. The data contains activities and the times they start. There is a stored procedure which runs daily that converts these start times into intervals.This works the vast majority of the time, but there have been about a dozen days in the last year that this has failed due to the arithmetic overflow error. I've attempted to change data types from INT to Numeric, but this hasn't solved the problem. Any help/thoughts/ideas are greatly appreciated!

The stored procedure:

```
insert into [DB].[dbo].[Final_Table]
([resourceName]
      ,[eventdatetime]
      ,[EV2]
      ,[IntervalTime]
      ,[event])

(
SELECT DS1.[resourceName]
      ,DS2.[eventdatetime]
      ,DS1.[eventdatetime] as EV2
      ,CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(SECOND, DS2.[eventdatetime], DS1.[eventdatetime]) * 1000, 0), 114) AS [IntervalTime]
      ,DS2.[event]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Staging_Table] DS1

INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Staging_Table] DS2
    ON DS1.[resourceName] = DS2.[resourceName]
    AND DS1.[ID] = DS2.[ID] + 1)
```

The staging table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Staging_Table](
    [ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [resourceName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [eventdatetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [event] [varchar](9) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data in staging table:

[image]

The final table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Final_Table](
    [resourceName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [eventdatetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [EV2] [datetime] NULL,
    [IntervalTime] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [event] [varchar](9) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Final Table data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post. Clearly I've been staring at my screen too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions return an `INT`. Then you are multiplying it with 1000 to get the results from seconds in milliseconds.

But, sometimes this may result in `overflow`. For example:

```
DECLARE @A DATETIME2 = '2000-01-01'
       ,@B DATETIME2 = '2001-01-01'


SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, @A, @B) * 1000
```

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 5 Arithmetic overflow error
> converting expression to data type int.

So, just cast to `BIGINT` first:

```
DECLARE @A DATETIME2 = '2000-01-01'
       ,@B DATETIME2 = '2001-01-01'


SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @A, @B) AS BIGINT) * 1000
```

---

Actually, the above will not solve your issue, because if you check the [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

> The number argument cannot exceed the range of int. In the following
> statements, the argument for number exceeds the range of int by 1.
> These statements both return the following error message: "Msg 8115,
> Level 16, State 2, Line 1. Arithmetic overflow error converting
> expression to data type int."

That's mean that even you pass `BIGINT` value to it (after the cast), you will continue to get this error:

```
DECLARE @C BIGINT = 31622400000    
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND,  @C  , 0)
```

You will need to handle this situations in a different way. For example, set a `MAX` value if your differences exceed the `INT`.

```
DECLARE @A DATETIME2 = '2000-01-01'
       ,@B DATETIME2 = '2001-01-01'

SELECT TRY_CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @A, @B) AS BIGINT) * 1000 AS INT)
```

Comment: Probably `DATEDIFF_BIG()` is a better option (`DECLARE @A DATETIME2 = '1900-01-01', @B DATETIME2 = '2001-01-01'`returns an error).

Comment: @Zhorov It will face the `DATEADD` limitation again.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `DATEADD()` expects `int`. But the answer is a possible solution, +1.